# How to edit search engines in Firefox Quantum?

Tags: firefox, search-engines

I use several search engines in Firefox Quantum, each with  1 - 3 letter shortcuts (`w` for Wikipedia, `m` for Google Maps, etc.), and I need to modify the URL of one of the search engines.

I remember there was some XML file in past versions, but this seems to have changed over time:

- Where are these now saved and how do I edit them?
- Can I create a custom one?

Answer (score 9):

In Ubuntu 16, FireFox 58, the configuration file is compressed into the `.mozlz4` format:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<name>.default/search.json.mozlz4
```

You can decompress/compress this file via the python lz4 library:

- Decompress:

  ```py
  import lz4.block as lb

  infile = '/path/to/infile'
  outfile = '/path/to/outfile'

  inf = open(infile, 'rb')
  inf.read(8)
  data = lb.decompress(inf.read())
  outf = open(outfile, 'wb')
  outf.write(data)
  ```
- Modify content as needed
- Compress:

  ```py
  import lz4.block as lb

  infile = '/path/to/infile'
  outfile = '/path/to/outfile'

  inf = open(infile, 'rb')
  data = lb.compress(inf.read())
  data = b'mozLz40\0' + data
  outf = open(outfile, 'wb')
  outf.write(data)
  ```

Comment: There's a Firefox addon that makes the process of adding and editing search engines a little easier. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozlz4-edit/

Answer (score 6):

A quick search bookmark is a regular bookmark with a 'keyword' in the properties, so you can edit and configure your quick search engines via the bookmark configuration. Tested in FF Quantum 63.0.3. Simply

1. Open *Bookmark Sidebar* via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
2. Filter for the bookmark you want to edit [`wikipe`] and right-click it
3. Edit the URL and keyword to your needs: [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible with Firefox Quantum anymore, although I remember doing the same many years ago by editing the XML file manually to adjust search settings (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963256/adding-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox)).

- I've tried to find a file containing search engine settings by looking for a phrase with one of my search engine's name recursively in Firefox profile directory, however none of the returned files referred to search engines:

  ```bsh
  grep -Ri 'some search engine name' ~/.mozilla/firefox/<name>.default/
  ```

Alternative solutions that allow the generation of a new custom search engine:

- [Mycroft Project](https://mycroftproject.com/submitos.html): 
   Intuitive and user-friendly, with great customization options
- [Ready2Search](https://ready.to/search/en/): 
   When creating a search engine with an icon, ensure the image file has an extension (`.gif`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, etc.), else it will error with incorrect/unsupported file format.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to edit `.mozlz4` files is using the [mozlz4-edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozlz4-edit/) Firefox addon.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines are stored in `search.json.mozlz4` file inside [user profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data). It is regular `JSON` compressed with `LZ4`. Besides using multiple command-line utilities and scripts (see [how to decompress jsonlz4 files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326897/how-to-decompress-jsonlz4-files-firefox-bookmark-backups-using-the-command-lin)), you can edit it with [mozlz4-edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozlz4-edit/) add-on.